# thymeleaf fragments - html modal for confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, thymeleaf

I have a confirmation dialog that is resurfacing on some pages so I thought that I can make a thymeleaf fragment for it.

I created a new html page (modal.html) and a div containing the modal:

```
<div th:fragment="confirm">
    <div id="confirm" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
           <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Please confirm</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                   <a id="btn-confirm" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Confirm</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I included it like this on the pages:

```
<div th:include="fragments/modal :: confirm"></div>
```

This kind of syntax worked for my header. 
The problem is that it is visible at all times now.
When I include the same modal code on the page directly it only pops up when toggled.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"`button?

Comment: Yes I have a button with the attributes data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#confirm"

Comment: Then you should compare the rendered working solution and the rendered fragment solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *modal* CSS class has **display: none;**, so it's hidden by default.

Your div that includes the fragment probably is inside an element that has a CSS class that sets the [CSS display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to something different than *none*, and overwrites the *modal* CSS class.

Check in the developers extension (F12) the style of the element to see what overwrites the **display** property

And make sure you include

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
```